# Get the X first nodes in a Xdocument object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So far, I used this line of code to get the id value of the first "press_release" node:

```
int lastDistantPrID = xdoc.Descendants("press_release").Select(pr => Convert.ToInt32(pr.Attribute("id").Value)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead of this, i now need to get in a list of int, the id's of the 5 first press_release nodes. I can't find the correct method to use to achieve this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try learning things rather than posting question for everything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Take` method

```
xdoc.Descendants("press_release")
    .Select(pr => Convert.ToInt32(pr.Attribute("id").Value))
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```